# How to Disable today's date using date pickers - material ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

I'm working on a react project where I'm using [material-ui-date-pickers](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/getting-started/installation) and i want to disable today's date since the project is based on manufacturing products, expiration date of products and billing.
Since Manufacturing date and expiration date cannot be same ,I want to disable today's date for expiration date. I see props `minDate , maxDate` can be used , but is it possible to disable today's date using the same?
Below is my code.

```
      <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>
            <KeyboardDatePicker
              autoOk={true}
              variant='inline'
              inputVariant='outlined'
              format={dateFormat}
              fullWidth
              name='expirationDate'
              value={expirationDate}
              onChange={ (date) => handleDate(date)}
              placeholder={dateFormat}
              size='small'
              disableFuture={true}
              views={['date', 'month', 'year']}
            />
          </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this be can done using JavaScript date method and using the props `minDate , maxDate`.

First declare the new date using

```
const today = new Date();
```

and in `maxDate` prop subtract today's date by 1 to get yesterday's date and give it as `maxDate`.

```
maxDate={today.setDate(today.getDate() - 1)}
```

So your complete code will be

```
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>
            <KeyboardDatePicker
              autoOk={true}
              variant='inline'
              inputVariant='outlined'
              format={dateFormat}
              fullWidth
              name='expirationDate'
              value={expirationDate}
              onChange={ (date) => handleChangeDate(date)}
              placeholder={dateFormat}
              size='small'
              disableFuture={true}
              views={['date', 'month', 'year']}
              maxDate={today.setDate(today.getDate() - 1)}
            />
          </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `disablePast` flag for the `KeyboardDatePicker` element:

```js
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>
    <KeyboardDatePicker
        autoOk={true}
        disablePast={true}
        variant='inline'
        inputVariant='outlined'
        format={dateFormat}
        fullWidth={true}
        name='expirationDate'
        value={expirationDate}
        onChange={(date) => handleDate(date)}
        placeholder={dateFormat}
        size='small'
        disableFuture={true}
        views={['date', 'month', 'year']}
    />
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```